# making elasticsearch and bigquery work together

Tags: elasticsearch, google-bigquery

I have a web app that displays the analysis data in browser with elasticsearch as backend data store.

Everything was cool as elasticsearch was handling about 1TB data and search queries were blazing fast.

Then came the decision to add data from all services into the app, close to a peta byte, and we switched to bigquery.[yes, we abandoned the elasticsearch and started querying bigquery directly ].

Now users of my app are complaining that their queries are slow, they are taking seconds (4~10~15), which used to display under a second before.

Naturally the huge amount of data here is to be blamed but I am wondering if there is a way to bring back elasticsearch into the game and make elasticsearch and bigquery play together nicely so that I can get the petaytes of storage from bigquery but still retain the lightspeed search of elasticsearch.

I am sure I am not the first one to face this issue rather I believe I am bit late to the bigquery party so I should be able to reap the benefits of delayed entry by getting all the problems already solved.

Thanks in advance if you can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Are you [clustering your data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)? What kind of queries are you running?

Comment: 1) Use BigQuery to do the data processing on huge datasets. Based on your search criteria/requirements, summary/aggregate your processed datasets to several small datasets.
2) Push the small datasets to Elasticsearch. Your app facing the end user will query from elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common pattern I see deployed by customers:

- Use Elasticsearch to display results from the latest day/week - whatever fits within Elasticsearch's RAM.
- Use BigQuery for everything else.

In this way your users will get sub-second results for 90% of their queries, and they will also be able to go wherever they want to go if Elasticsearch can't find an answer within its resources.

I'm not sure what are your users interfaces for getting data - but that's where this logic would need to be deployed.

(of course, expect improvements in the connections and speed as tech progresses)